# How to pass compile time parameter for Yocto project?

Tags: yocto, bitbake

I am new to Yocto build environment. I have a C code which has some code as below:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main ()
{
    printf("HELLO WORLD\n");

#ifdef MYDEF
    printf("MYDEF is defined\n");
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

I want to pass a flag/parameter MYDEF in local.conf file. I tried following defines but they didn't work. Any thoughts on what am I doing wrong and what possibly can fix it?

```
MYDEF = 'y'
MYDEF ?= 'y'
MYDEF ??= 'y'
CFLAGS = "-DMYDEF"
TARGET_CFLAGS = "-DMYDEF"
BUILD_CFLAGS = "-DMYDEF"
```

Thanks.

Comment: Do you use a makefile or plain c code?

Comment: In this setup I am not using Makefile. I know how to do this using Makefile by passing something using -DMYDEF but this is a yocto based build system and I have no clue what does it generate behind the curtain. I just want a way to tell Yocto's bitbake command that please pass MYDEF as a defined parameter. Any thoughts??

Comment: Then @astor555 answer will work out. Yocto is not doing anything special. You need to use ${CC} as he did, everything else is managed

Answer (score 1):

I was able to create a example recipe with compiling Your sample code:

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://hello_test.cpp"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit native

MYDEF = "y"

do_compile (){
  ${CC} -DMYDEF -o hello_test ${S}/hello_test.cpp
}

do_install () {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install ${B}/hello_test ${D}/${bindir}
}
```

And the proof of execution *hello_test* binary:

```
$ ./hello_test 
HELLO WORLD
MYDEF is defined
```

Comment: Hi astro555, Thanks for your answer. It is really helpful. However requirement for me is to put this MYDEF = "y" in local.conf file because I am not supposed to modify .bb or .bbappend file. If you know answer to this please let me know.

Comment: Did You try move this line _MYDEF = "y"_ into local.conf it's works. For checking which variables and where are they generated You can use _-e_ option (e.g. in Your case _bitbake -e hello-test | grep MYDEF_). If You can't modify those layer's, another solution is to create new layer for You appends (I'm assume that You can modify bblayers.conf).

Comment: I did try by adding that line in local.conf to begin with. When it didn't work I posted question here. Did you do any other changes besides in local.conf file??

Comment: The answer would not be correct. MYDEF is defined because it is forced in the do_compile function. Actual compilation It is not getting affected recipe variable.

Answer (score 0):

Taking the same code as @astor555, there are some problems in the way the flag is handled.

```
LICENSE = "CLOSED"

SRC_URI = "file://hello_test.cpp"
S = "${WORKDIR}"

inherit native

MYDEF ?= "-DMYDEF"

do_compile (){
  ${CC} ${MYDEF} -o hello_test ${S}/hello_test.cpp
}

do_install () {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install ${B}/hello_test ${D}/${bindir}
}
```

**Note the definition of MYDEF variable, and how it is referenced inside the do_compile funciton.** 
Then in your local.conf you could either disable it by overriding its value:

```
MYDEF = ""
```

or force it like:

```
MYDEF = "-DMYDEF"
```

But as in the recipe the weak assignment ?= is used, it will be the value by default, so you dont require to add anything in the local.conf if you want it to be defined.